# error lunching ASP.net Web application from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-8

i have worked on ASP.net Web application in my local host and it worked perfectly, when i move the application folder to the Test server with IIS 8 it worked the first time but every time i modified a page in my local and move it to server i can not see the changes, 
when i created ASP.net Web site i dont face any issue with that, can you please provide with the correct way of copy web application to another server?
also i enabled the custom error in webl.config but i am getting another error
[image: error in IIS server]

any suggestion

thank you

Comment: Please post the contents of web.config.

Comment: please confirm you are uploading only updated pages or replacing full application

Comment: thank you for the reply, i managed to solve this issue, but i am facing another issue now, when i update the page code behind its not reflected in the development server, is there any other way to deploy the update pages in web application?

Comment: for code behind you can just replace yourfilename.dll on server

Comment: thanks for the reply, it worked, can you please post your reply as an answer @shreesha

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the conversation in comment section.when you are publishing your website you will get three options

[image]

**Allow this precompiled site to be updatable**:Leaving it checked allows you to make certain changes to the .Aspx files after it has been deployed without recompiling (ex = move the position of a control or add some additional HTML markup).

**use fixed naming and single page assemblies**:Fixed named assemblies provide flexiblity in page level updates. Since each page will have its own named assembly (instead of a random name) it is easy to update the application by just updating the required assembly.that said if you have made changes to single code behind file then you can easily replace particular .dll file on server with your changed .dll file and the site will work.
Disadvantage is the large number of assemblies (difficult to maintain) and also slight performance hit would be there.

**enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies**:This is primarily for higher security

For more information check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx)